# is it possible to use Holder inequality in this way?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, holder-inequality

In the book Superlinear Parabolic Problems Blow-up, Global Existence and Steady States, page 492 this equation appears in which the book says it uses Holder inequality
[image]

My question is whether it's really possible to use Holder this way, that is (Here $|\Omega|< \infty$):

$$ \int_{\Omega}u^{m}dx \int_{\Omega}u^{p}dx \leq |\Omega| \int_{\Omega}u^{m+p}dx$$

I've tried using Classic Holder inequality and this reverse version [Reverse Holder Inequality $\|fg\|_1\geq\| f\|_{\frac{1}{p}}\|g\|_{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946616/reverse-holder-inequality-fg-1-geq-f-frac1p-g-frac1p-1#) , but nothing comes close to what the book says. Another thing is that the book does not assume anything about $m$ before making this inequality, only later it says that $m+1 \geq p$

Comment: Use Hölder with exponents $r = (m + p)/m$ and $r' = (m+p)/p$ to get $\int u^m\le |\Omega|^{p/(m+p)}\int u^{m+p}$. The other is similar.

Comment: thank you, it worked, there was only one thing missing, which was the power $\dfrac{m}{m+p} $in the integral $\int u^{m+p}$.